# How do I solve this issue?

Tags: command

I tried to install a package in command prompt (actin) from python.but always there is an error. I tried to solve this issue but I could not.

The package is (Actin) to calculate the indices in science.
this is an error:

This is what I do:

```
C:\Users\MAISSA>**\pip install actin

Collecting actin
Using cached actin-1.3.6.tar.gz (52.0 MB)
```

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 22]
> Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\MAISSA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ysinw5a9\actin_8d5ed7c1aad943cbba7a60ea2545108f\actin/test_files/2010-09-18T23:42:36.178_spec.rdb

Comment: I would suggest a more appropriate and related question title

Answer (score 0):

The Python OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument problem occurs，1.The file path is faulty（The file path does not exist, or the string is inconsistent with the file path）  2.When there are strange characters in front of the path,You should have thought it was because of coding（Whether it's ANSI coding or UTF-8 coding or some other coding reason）

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).